# Python 3.5 - Name 'await' is not defined

Tags: python, async-await, coroutine, python-3.5

I'm trying to experiment with the new `await` syntax for coroutines in Python 3.5.

I had a simple example like this:

```py
#! /usr/bin/env python
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
def adder(*args, delay):
    while True:
        yield from asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(sum(args))


def main():
    asyncio.Task(adder(1, 2, 3, delay=5))
    asyncio.Task(adder(10, 20, delay=3))

    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I changed the `yield from` line to use the `await` keyword:

`await asyncio.sleep(delay)`

And I get `SyntaxError`:

```
  File "./test.py", line 8
    await asyncio.sleep(delay)
                ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

So I try `await (asyncio.sleep(delay))` just to see what happens:

```
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<adder() done, defined at c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\coroutines.py:198> exception=NameError("name 'await' is not defined",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\coroutines.py", line 200, in coro
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "./test.py", line 8, in adder
    await (asyncio.sleep(delay))
NameError: name 'await' is not defined
Task exception was never retrieved
future: <Task finished coro=<adder() done, defined at c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\coroutines.py:198> exception=NameError("name 'await' is not defined",)>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\tasks.py", line 239, in _step
    result = coro.send(value)
  File "c:\python35\Lib\asyncio\coroutines.py", line 200, in coro
    res = func(*args, **kw)
  File "./test.py", line 8, in adder
    await (asyncio.sleep(delay))
NameError: name 'await' is not defined
```

Am I using the keyword wrong? Why is `await` not defined? I got my `await` syntax from [this post.](http://makina-corpus.com/blog/metier/2015/python-http-server-with-the-new-async-await-syntax)

Just to cover all my bases:

```sh
$ /usr/bin/env python --version

Python 3.5.0
```

#### Edit:

I suppose adding the parens to the `await` line is trying to call a function `await()` - so that's why that doesn't work and gives me a `NameError`. But why doesn't the keyword get recognized in either example?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You must declare your function as `async` to use `await`. Replacing `yield from` is not sufficient.

```
#! /usr/bin/env python
import asyncio

@asyncio.coroutine
async def adder(*args, delay):
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(delay)
        print(sum(args))


def main():
    asyncio.Task(adder(1, 2, 3, delay=5))
    asyncio.Task(adder(10, 20, delay=3))
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    loop.run_forever()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare your function as `async` to make this work.  The `await` keyword will only be enabled if you include an a function declared with `async def` in your file – see [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#transition-plan) for details.

Answer (score 1):

Per [PEP 492](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0492/#why-not-a-future-import), the `await` keyword is only recognized in functions defined with the new `async def` syntax, which removes the need for a `__future__` import.